# Error: Invalid use of flexible array member

Tags: c, arrays, struct, flexible-array-member

I don't know why this code give this error. What should I do? The error is as follows:

> Invalid use of flexible array member

on this line:

```
new_buffer->array_msg =array;
```

here if are larger section of code:

```
   typedef struct buffer {
    int size;
    int T;
    int D;
    int msg_presenti;

    pthread_cond_t not_full;
    pthread_cond_t not_empty;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    msg_t * array_msg[];

} buffer_t;

buffer_t * buffer_init(unsigned int maxsize){
    buffer_t * new_buffer = malloc( sizeof(buffer_t) + maxsize * sizeof(msg_t) );

    msg_t * array[maxsize];
    new_buffer->array_msg =array;
    new_buffer->size=maxsize;
    return new_buffer;
}
// deallocazione di un buffer
```

Comment: Voting to reopen the question now has enough information to answer.

Answer (score 2):

This line is sufficient to allocate space for both your *struct* and the flexible array member:

```
buffer_t * new_buffer = malloc( sizeof(buffer_t) + maxsize * sizeof(msg_t *) );
                                ^                  ^
                                1                  2
```

`1` will allocate memory for the *struct* while `2` will allocate space for your *flexible array member*, so your function should look like this:

```
buffer_t * buffer_init(unsigned int maxsize)
{
    buffer_t * new_buffer = malloc( sizeof(buffer_t) + maxsize * sizeof(msg_t) );

    new_buffer->size=maxsize;
    return new_buffer;
}
```

If we look to the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)  section `6.7.2.1` Structure and union specifiers paragraph *17* gives the following example:

> EXAMPLE After the declaration:
>
> ```
> struct s { int n; double d[]; };
> ```
>
> the structure struct `s` has a flexible array member `d`. A typical way to use this is:
>
> ```
> int m = /* some value */;
> struct s *p = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + sizeof (double [m]));
> ```
>
> and assuming that the call to `malloc` succeeds, the object pointed to by `p` behaves, for most purposes, as if `p` had been declared as:
>
> ```
> struct { int n; double d[m]; } *p;
> ```
>
> (there are circumstances in which this equivalence is broken; in particular, the offsets of member `d` might not be the same).